# How do I start Edge on Windows from WSL2?

Tags: microsoft-edge, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I can run `code` to start VSCode from inside WSL2.

How would I start Edge (the current Chromium based one)?

I have tried:

```
~/Code/company/workshops-website$ cmd.exe /c 'start microsoft-edge:\\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\mike\Code\company\workshops-website\index.html'
'\\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\mike\Code\company\workshops-website'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
```

It starts Edge but doesn't open `index.html` (instead Edge searches for it)

**How would I start Edge (the Windows app) from inside WSL2?**

I'm comfortable making bash aliases, functions, etc.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`$ wslview index.html`

Will open the file in your default browser on Windows.

wslview is packaged in [wslutilities](https://github.com/wslutilities/wslu#feature) which comes pre-installed on Ubuntu on WSL and some other WSL distros.

Comment: Perfect, thanks Hayden! I've aliased this to `open` in my `.bashrc` as it's easier to remember. 

Comment: It's no longer pre-installed starting from Ubuntu 22.04 LTS - https://wslutiliti.es/wslu/install.html#ubuntu

Answer (score 9):

If you wish to use the default Windows browser automatically, e.g. when using 'az login', add these lines to your shell's RC e.g. .bashrc or .zshrc:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
export BROWSER=/usr/bin/wslview
```

Comment: This answer was exactly what I needed for getting `gcloud auth login` to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I think you can try this

Add this line:

```
alias browser="/mnt/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Microsoft/Edge/Application/msedge.exe"
```

to `.bashrc`
the value is the path of my browser
so if you type `browser`, the microsoft edge will pop up just like type `code` and  vscode pops up

Comment: Works like a charm on my system with WSL2. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way to do this is to use `explorer.exe`. You can use `explorer.exe` to open anything web related in your default browser.

So edit your `.bash_aliases` (or create it) to add this line:

```bash
alias browser="explorer.exe"
```

Then you can open your HTML files in your default browser like this:

```bash
$ browser index.html
```

You might also want to set the `BROWSER` variable:

```bash
export BROWSER="explorer.exe"
```

This will allow apps to open links.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to differ depending on Distro (according to the other answers). For instance, I have Kali installed in the WSL2 (Windows 11) and if I want to run the new Edge from there, I first have to install it, [Edge-Developer Edition Install Debain-based](https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download?platform=linux-deb), [Regular Edge](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge). The second link, you need to scroll all the way to the bottom and pick *Linux* from the drop-down menu. Once installed it will be in your "Start Menu". Again, I am using Kali and have not tried the others lately on the WSL, but as far as Kali is concerned, as long as the WSL is running, you can launch any Linux program from the Windows Start Menu!. You only really need a desktop env, if you **need** a Linux desktop env, otherwise just use the apps alongside Windows...I love it!
[image: WSL2 Running. No Commands. Apps Running]

Again, this may be "Distro-specific", but in the picture I tried to show how I can launch apps that are installed in the WSL without any commands or changing desktop environments in order for them to run. Same goes for Edge, I suggest download the **.deb** file and installing it that way.

Comment: My question was about starting edge for Windows. I don’t think edge for Linux existed at the time I asked it.

Comment: Yea, Edge from the WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux), same thing. As long as the "New" version of Edge has been out, it has been available on Linux. I was responding to this statement in bold "**How would I start Edge from inside WSL2?**"

Comment: @slybandit70 It's implicit I was asking about the Windows app Edge (rather than asking how to start a Linux app from Linux) but I've edited the question to make that clearer.